# arrange the array in an order such that the even values are followed by odd values in the array

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

this is the program I made ,if I input [13,11,10,17,18] i get the output [12,13,17,11,10]. I do not understand what mistake I am making. somebody please help me understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
     
int main()
{
  int* ptr;
  int n,j,i,num,v;

  printf("Enter number of elements:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Entered number of elements: %d\n", n);
  ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d",&v);
    ptr[i] = v;
  }
  i=0;
  j=0;
  while(i<5){
    j++;
    if (ptr[j]%2==0 && i%2==0){
      num=ptr[i];
      ptr[i]=ptr[j];
      ptr[j]=num;
    }
    if (ptr[j]%2!=0 && i%2 !=0){
      num=ptr[i];
      ptr[i]=ptr[j];
      ptr[j]=num;
    }
    
    if (j==4){
      i++;
      j=0;
    }
  }

  printf("The elements of the array are: ");
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If *ever* there was a candidate for single-line step-debugging, this is it.

Comment: Pleae provide all the return values of your uses of `scanf()`. You ignore them at your own risk.

Comment: This is a strange way to do a nested loop.  It would be a lot simpler to read this code if you had two for-loops: one inside the other.  My guess is that you always restart the j-loop at zero, which could very well corrupt the earlier "good-until-index-i" state you already computed.  Try setting `j=i` when you reset it, would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: "if I input [13,11,10,17,18] i get the output [12,13,17,11,10]" Cannot reproduce, I get "The elements of the array are: 18, 13, 17, 11, 10, " Please double check that you really get different values than input, because the code looks like it only fails on reordering. Also please provide the content of the array after each step and point out at which point the values change instead of only the order.

Comment: An *exact* expected output is warranted as part of your post. to simply swap-iterate over the sequence on condition of even vs odd is an O(n) algorithm, and requires no nested loop. That should be easy enough provided there are no other specific expectations of the final ordering *other* than evens first, then odds.

Comment: I know you will not do this, but anyway... **Edit you question** adding what is the aim of your program: do you only want to have even elements before odd ones, or do they need to be sorted? Remove all stdin stuff: no manual input. Provide in your [mcve] an array initialized with the example data. Then clearly provide your output for that example and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried to tell you how you should have written you program, but you didn't listen:

1. Make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
2. A MCVE needs all the includes
3. No interactive stuff. You need to run and run and run your program in a debugger. You don't want to put data in manually every single time.
4. You want many tests, and you want to repeat them, so that when you fix one, you don't break another.
5. Make a function which does the job.
6. Free your memory!

Now to the solution: your idea of a solution was fine apart from the stuff about indexes. It's pretty similar to the one you will find down here. The only difference is that I put the odd numbers al the end to avoid checking elements multiple times.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void evenodd(int *v, size_t n)
{   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (i < n && v[i] % 2 == 0) {
            ++i;
        }
        --n;
        while (i < n && v[n] % 2) {
            --n;
        }
        if (i < n) {
            int tmp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[n];
            v[n] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

bool is_evenodd(int *v, size_t n)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < n && v[i] % 2 == 0) {
        ++i;
    }
    while (i < n && v[i] % 2 != 0) {
        ++i;
    }

    return i == n;
}

void main_test(const int *v, size_t n)
{
    int *v1 = memcpy(malloc(n * sizeof(int)), v, n * sizeof(int));

    evenodd(v1, n);

    if (is_evenodd(v1, n)) {
        printf("Ok!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Fail!\n");
    }

    free(v1);
}

int main(void) 
{
    main_test((int[]) { 1 }, 0);
    main_test((int[]) { 1 }, 1);
    main_test((int[]) { 2 }, 1);
    main_test((int[]) { 1, 2 }, 2);
    main_test((int[]) { 1, 3 }, 2);
    main_test((int[]) { 2, 1 }, 2);
    main_test((int[]) { 2, 4 }, 2);

    main_test((int[]) { 1, 3, 2 }, 3);
    main_test((int[]) { 1, 4, 2 }, 3);

    size_t n = 1000;
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = rand();
    }
    main_test(a, n);
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code :

```
int even_index = 0; //start index
int odd_index = 4; //end index

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   if(ptr[i] % 2 == 0){
      int temp = ptr[even_index];
      ptr[even_index++] = ptr[i]; //swapping values and incrementing even_index
      ptr[i] = temp;
   }else{
      int temp = ptr[odd_index];
      ptr[odd_index--] = ptr[i];
      ptr[i] = temp;
   }
}
```

or you can also count the number of even numbers in the digits during input and assign odd_value = even_num // number of even digits

Comment: I think OP wants to understand their own mistake, at least that is what they are asking about. Providing an unexplained solution does not seem to answer that question.

Comment: ptr is input as well as reused/over written.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I solved it....

see the even numbers always end up in even indexes so we need to set a pointer on those even index(current index) and search for any even number after the current index.

if we find any(even number) we swap the current index value with the even number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
  int main()
{
  int* ptr;
  int n,j,i,num,v;

  printf("Enter number of elements:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Entered number of elements: %d\n", n);
  ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  scanf("%d", &v);
  ptr[i] = v;
  }
  i=0;
  j=0;
  while(i<n && j<n){

  if (ptr[j]%2==0){
    num=ptr[i];
    ptr[i]=ptr[j];
    ptr[j]=num;
    i+=2;
    j=i;
  }
  j++;
  
  }

  printf("The elements of the array are: ");
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  printf("%d, ", ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: "ok so I solved it...." No. Your program fails for an arbitrary large number of cases, such as: [1, 4, 2]. Test it [here](https://ideone.com/lE9VQF). Your assumption "see the even numbers always end up in even indexes", is just plain wrong. Think of an array filled with only even numbers, of course half will be in even indexes and half will be at odd ones.

Answer (score -1):

If this problem is to sort an array in order (descending) and then further place all even values before odd values I would recommend:

1. Sort the array
2. Swap and shift any odd numbers with the even numbers

Here's a naive implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
int lastEven = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 && (arr[i + 1] % 2 == 0)) {
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = tmp;
        lastEven = i;
    } else if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && lastEven-i > 1) {
        for (int j = i; j > lastEven; j--) {
            tmp = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
        lastEven++;
    }
}
```

Given the input `[13,11,10,17,18]` this will first sort the array (`[18,17,13,11,10]`) then separate the evens and odds (`[18,10,17,13,11]`)

Comment: If you need to ask clarification questions before you can answer please wait for your commenting privilege to do so. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Doing an odd/even reshuffle after sorting is exactly the same as doing it without sorting at all.

Comment: Odd/even reshuffle must happen post sort since it is not known if the input array is presorted. If the array isn't presorted the result will be `[10,18,13,11,17]`. The sort satisfies the "in order" req

Comment: @Yunnosch the answer can be edited once the asker provides clarity if necessary.

Comment: Then phrase it as an assertive answer with the intention to adapt it to incoming info or ...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Ah understood. I will go ahead and update the answer now. Thanks for clarifying